# Sorting multiple arrays based on one

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have 2 arrays: the first one contains a list of score numbers, and the second contains a list of countries with the same number of elements. Each country is linked with its proper score during the input. So, let's say the input arrays are the following:

```
var scores = [2, 5, 3, 1, 4];
var countries = ["Canada", "Macau", "Sweden", "France", "China"];
```

I need the following output:

```
scores = [1,2,3,4,5]
countries = [ "France", "Canada", "Sweden", "China", "Macau" ]
```

A possible solution I can know of is to transform the arrays into a single array containing a list of "score=country" pairs. But I wonder if it's possible to do a miracle with the Array.sort() method, since it accepts a callback function. Any other solutions are welcome too.

Comment: It's an interesting problem for the sake of solving a problem, but why would you *not* use an array of objects for that data?

Comment: Why an array of objects, when just one object will do?

Comment: @vol7ron - to allow easy sorting?

Comment: `[ {'Canada':2}, {'Macau':5}, … ]` is easier to sort than `{'Canada':2, 'Macau':5, … }`??

Comment: @vol7ron - Yes. How do you extract the data in score order from `{'Canada':2, 'Macau':5, … }`? And if you change your mind and want alphabetical order after all?

Comment: @nnnnnn you'd loop once and rebuild an array; for sorting the easiest way may be to have an array of arrays, rather than array of objects. I suspect the best choice would be dependent on his implementation.  If you build the object as my answer with score as the key, you could use the sort of `scores` to do the ordering (the caveat would no longer apply)

Comment: I should add that @nnnnnn approach to array of objects is more common -- it seems in the past that was my go to and is more versatile for sorting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a hash as your intuition was leading you to:

```js
 
var scores = [2, 5, 3, 1, 4];
var countries = ["Canada", "Macau", "Sweden", "France", "China"];

var score = {};
for( var i=0,n=scores.length; i<n; i++){
  score[scores[i]] = countries[i];
}

for( var key in keys=Object.keys(score).sort() ){
  var prop = keys[key];
  console.log(prop, score[prop]);
}
```

#### Caveats:

1. Using dfsq's reverse of this (i.e.,`{country:number}`) may be better.  In the above, the keys (numbers) may be turned into strings, which may have unwanted sort when there are more countries; JavaScript may sort the keys by the first ASCII character like (e.g.,`['1','10',…,'19','2','20',…,'29','3',…]`).

#### Benefits:

1. If the scores are actually IDs, and you are expecting to work with, it makes sense to use that as the key, otherwise if you will be doing lookups by country name to retrieve the score, it makes sense to make the country name the key.

Answer (score 0):

First, make a copy.

```
 var countries2 = countries.slice(0);
```

Use [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) to get the array index from the country name and use that to look up the corresponding score.

You needed to make that copy because otherwise the index of a country might move around as the array is sorted.

```
 function byScores(a,b){
      return scores[countries.indexOf(a)]-scores[countries.indexOf(b)];
 }
 countries2.sort(byScores);
 --> [ "France", "Canada", "Sweden", "China", "Macau" ]
```

Answer (score 0):

The `callback` is for the so called `comparator` (`compareFunction`). You can zip them and sort on keys.

Below is an example using `lodash`:

```
_ = require('lodash')
var obj = _.zipObjects(scores, countries)
var scores = _.keys(obj).sort()
var countries = scores.map(function(elem) { return obj[elem]; })
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using Bubble sort technique to sort two arrays:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var scores = [2, 5, 3, 1, 4];
var countries = ["Canada", "Macau", "Sweden", "France", "China"];

function sortArray () {
    var temp;

    for (var i = 0; i < scores.length; i++) {
        for (var j = i + 1; j < scores.length; j++) {
            if (scores[i] > scores[j]) {
                temp = scores[i];
                scores[i] = scores[j];
                scores[j] = temp;

                temp = countries[i];
                countries[i] = countries[j];
                countries[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
    alert("Scores : " + scores.join(", ") + "\nCountrie:" + countries.join(", "));
}
window.onload = sortArray;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with the help of helper country-score map object.

```js
var scores = [2, 5, 3, 1, 4];
var countries = ["Canada", "Macau", "Sweden", "France", "China"];

// Build helper object: {Canada: 2, Macau: 5, Sweden: 3, France: 1, China: 4}
var scoresMap = {};
scores.forEach(function(el, i) {
    scoresMap[countries[i]] = el;
});

countries.sort(function(a, b) {
    return scoresMap[a] - scoresMap[b];
});

document.write(JSON.stringify(countries, null, 4));
```